# How to get the page_source to include shadow root elements in Appium/Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium, html-parsing

I have a parser for a given web page with a lot of nested shadow-root elements developed in Appium. Since it's extremely slow, I would like to move to BeatifulSoup to dump the HTML only once and then extract the information locally instead of sending hundreds of requests to the Appium server.

To do so I need to dump the HTML of the page generated by my appium script.

This is the current code that should parse the HTML:

`BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, "html.parser")`

The problem is that shadow root elements are not included and I can't seem to find a way to have a single HTML tree or at least a collection of DOM documents to search in.

Obviously I could access the shadow_root elements through Appium throughout the parsing step, but this would defy the purpose of using BeatifulSoup in the first place.

Any suggestion on how to get the shadow DOMs?